# Selecting part of entity into custom object with children objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a entity framework query like so -

```
var query = from tbl in db.myTable
            select new MyModel
            {
               id = tbl.id,
               start = tbl.start,
               end = tbl.end
            }
```

MyModel is the following -

```
public class MyModel
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public Range range  {get; set;} // contains start and end property
}
```

Is there anyway inside the query select to map the properties of myTable into range.start and range.end?

The only way i've found to get working is to add additional properties into the model like so -

```
public class MyModel
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string _start {get; set;}
   public string _end {get; set;}
   public Range range {get; set;} // contains start and end property
}
```

Then running some code after the query has completed that maps _start into range.start and _end into range.end.

The problem with this is that I foresee needing to map start/end into many custom sub models from the entity. I would need to always import the function from a common file and remember to run it after the query ran. It would be much cleaner if it was possible to just map them directly in the select like -

```
var query = from tbl in db.myTable
            select new MyModel
            {
               id = tbl.id,
               range.start = tbl.start,
               range.end = tbl.end
            }
```

or

```
var query = from tbl in db.myTable
            select new MyModel
            {
               id = tbl.id,
               range = new Range(tbl.end, tbl.start),
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
var query = from tbl in db.myTable
            select new MyModel
            {
               id = tbl.id,
               range = new Range
               {
                   start = tbl.start,
                   end = tbl.end
               }
            }
```

Comment: Yes very simple bit of a "duh" moment. Thanks for the help. Think the fact that you can't do something like "range = new Range(tbl.end, tbl.start)," was throwing me off a bit. Thanks again!